# Specific elements of map to list in dart (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `List` with multiple `Map`s in dart:

```
[{name: name1, id: 1259}, {name: name2, id: 2333}]
```

I would like to end up with a `List` that contains all the `id`s, like this.

```
[1259,2333, ... ]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data =  [{"name": "name1", "id": 1}, {"name": "name2", "id": 2}];
var list = [];
for (var item in data) {
  list.add(item["id"]);
}  

print("$list"); // [1, 2]
```

**Edit:**

You can directly use this (as suggested by Eugene)

```
var list = data.map((item) => item["id"]).toList();
list.forEach(print); // [1, 2]
```

Comment: @Eugene Same thing, i am not using IDE currently, so may have issue in fixing `(` `)` syntax. So I used this approach.